# Как сделать редирект на основе cookie?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Мне необходимо подменять URL-ы типа `site.com/...` на `site.com/city/...`, где значение `city` задается в куке.

Знаю, как можно изменять URL в .htaccess для юзера, но как сделать логику?

```
if ($_COOKIE['CITY']=1) {/*...*/} elseif ($_COOKIE['CITY']=2) {/*...*/}
```

Не понимаю.
Можно ли как то в .htaccess использовать условия или таким же образом через php подменять URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Можно с помощью .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*CITY=(\d+).*$
RewriteRule .* /city/%1 [L,R=302]
```

#### Можно с помощью PHP

```
// Если есть CITY в COOKIE и это целое число:
if (filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'CITY', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
    header("Location: /city/" . +$_COOKIE['CITY']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Сейчас я уже настроил, правило похожее использую, но получилось немного не то, что мне нужно.
Мне надо, что бы по адресу http://site.com/%1 (где %1 кука) выводилась страница http://site.com/, а сейчас я получаю карту сайта

Comment: @IvanBubliy согласитесь, что не видя вашего правила и сайта мне будет тяжело телепатировать вашу проблему. Пожалуйста, примите ответ, если он отвечает на ваш изначальный вопрос и задайте новый для вашей текущей проблемы